# Which CORBA implementation to use?

Tags: ipc, corba, zeromq

In some project, SysV IPC | Posix queues are used to exchange data between processes; with upcoming Windows port of a software, "an enormous amount of headache will be introduced without getting into using IDL and some middleware **like** CORBA", as someone said to me;

So, need an implementation of CORBA, that is enough standartized to be:

- available from C++ applications on Linux and Windows
- available from Java

Another problem is performance: it should not be ten times slow than provided by native IPC mechanism (with all the pain regarding implementing response waiting over IPC manually).

Timeout support is wanted too (max. 2 second waiting for IPC backend with exception throwing).

Currently looking to adopt ZeroMQ's IPC transport.

Comment: You said "somelike not CORBA", not "specifically CORBA".  Don't use CORBA unless you have to, it's a real pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [MICO](http://www.mico.org/index.html) for C++, it´s opensource and have a nice comunity.
For Java, i think JacORB is the best choice.
In my project, i work with [JacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/), MICO and [IIOP.NET](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/).